# Largest submatrix problem

Tags: algorithms

> Given a $N \times M$ matrix, I want to find the biggest submatrix, not necessarily a square one, that has the same value in all its entries.

For example, if $N=4$, $M=5$ and the matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\1&2&2&2&3\\4&2&2&2&6\\3&4&5&6&7 \end{bmatrix} $$

Then here the answer will be the submatrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2\\2&2&2 \end{bmatrix} $$

So I need to find upper leftmost coordinate of this submatrix that is $[2,2]$ and bottommost right coordinate that is $[3,4]$.

Comment: Looking through your past questions, I would advice you to tell us what you try instead of just stating the question, otherwise it would be quite difficult both for us to help you and for you to learn. Sure, you may know how to solve this or that problem now after someone posts a solution, but will you be able to solve any other problem without having to ask for help every time? It is hard to learn to do that with complete solutions, because the process of figuring out the solution is far more important...

Comment: @user21820 I thought of making a temporary matrix that will store in A[i,j] two values: the width and the height of the largest submatrix with the left upper corner at i,j but i am not able to device a proper algorithm for it

Comment: Okay great! Next time include after your problem a brief summary of what you've tried, like what you just said, so that it's easy to discuss how to go from there. If for a cell X you have the correct values for the cells on the right and the bottom, will you be able to get the correct value for X?

Comment: @user21820 yeah..right..and ok i will keep in mind

Comment: Great! Hope you can code the solution now! Remember to check the base cases carefully!

Comment: @user21820 nope could u please elaborate ?i am having a bit difficulty

Comment: Wait what's your definition of largest? If it is perimeter then this method works as it is, because perimeter increases by a constant when extending any rectangle. If it is area, then this method will need some modification, because for each cell X there may be multiple maximal solutions with top-left at X. If you store at each cell the list of optimal solutions for each possible height, then you can indeed obtain it from the lists for the right and bottom cells. This gives an $O(mn^2)$ algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach different from the one I gave in my comments that build upon your attempt, which is simply a different parametrization of the valid rectangles. In that parametrization a rectangle has (top-left,height,width) in that order, and the solution follows that.

Another parametrization is (top,bottom,left,right), and notice that for any (top,bottom) the valid rectangles are non-overlapping, so we can just scan one column at a time from left to right and try to extend the current rectangle, and once it fails we know that the next valid rectangle must have its left at the current column or later. Doing a little bit of preprocessing will enable us to query in $O(1)$ time for each column segment with given top and bottom, which I'll encourage you to figure out on your own; it's not hard. The preprocessing will take $O(mn)$ time and the rest will take $O(mn^2)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find ruby code in the accepted answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643908/getting-the-submatrix-with-maximum-sum).

Though, the answer there is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, and I believe that it is possible to use dynamic programming to speed this one up considerably.

**Update:** Sorry, the link actually shows a DP version. The naïve implementation is $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$.

Comment: @@TommyL i dont want maximum sum i want all elements in that submatrix should be same.Hope u are not misunderstanding the question

Comment: Yes, sorry I was not clear. The necessary code is below that link, but you'll need to adapt it to your problem. Since your problem is more heavily constrained it will have a smaller constant for the complexity, and thus run faster.

Comment: i am not finding any way to modify that code actually i know to calculate subarray with maximum sum using kadane for a 2d matrix but how to do this problem am not getting it

Comment: From the top of my head a naïve implementation would be to loop over every element ($\mathcal{O}(n^2)$), then start a new 2D loop ($\mathcal{O}(n^2)$) to see of this is the upper-left corner of the largest submatrix matrix. Compare the elements to the top-left corner. If they are different you break the loop and go on to test the next. Save the largest submatrix whenever you encounter a bigger one. This will be slow, though, so look at the link to see how to speed it up.

Comment: @TommyL: See my comment to user3001932, which will give an $O(mn)$ algorithm.

Comment: @user21820 Yep, seems like a good solution. Good job!

Comment: @TommyL: I was a bit too quick and forgot that there may be multiple solutions at each point, which matters if "largest" means "greatest area".

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple idea is that

```
- For each unique value (V) in matrix A[n][m]
    - Split matrix into connected components of value (V)
    - For each connected component (C)
         - Find largest rectangle in (C)
```

For more details

```
- For each position [i][j] in matrix A[n][m]
- - - If (visit(i, j) = false)
- - - - - Bfs from (i, j) to get current component (C)
- - - - - - - While containing positions in queue
- - - - - - - - - Get the position and pop out of queue
- - - - - - - - - Mark current position as visited and add to (C)
- - - - - - - - - Only move to its neighbour (i ± 1, j), (i, j ± 1)
- - - - - - - - - If (neighbour in the matrix) and (equal to A[i][j])
- - - - - - - - - - - add this position to queue
- - - - - 
- - - - - For each position (x, y) in component (C)
- - - - - - - For each width (w) = 1 -> n
- - - - - - - - - If (this width is invalid) then break
- - - - - - - - - For each height (h) = 1 -> m
- - - - - - - - - - - If (this height is invalid) break
- - - - - - - - - - - - - Update result with (n * m)
```

There is such optimizations using data structures and binary search to optimize to about $O(n \times m \times min(n, m) \times log(max(n, m)))$ or even $O(n \times m \times min(n, m))$

Actually there is a simpler idea where we fix 2 rows then move for each columns and by using DP and data structure to calculate in $O(1)$ or $O(log)$. Therefore we can also achieve the same complexity

But with this idea, we can observe that

- For any column, if we move from lower row to higher row each step, then we can calculate the current "height" of a column, which is the furthest distance in column that every elements in it are equal, in $O(1)$
- For a fixed row $(x)$, if we can find maximum height for each column, then you can calculate the maximum rectangle area $S(x)$ that contain atleast one element in this row in $O(K(x))$ where $K(x)$ is the number of $(i, j)$ in $(C)$ that $(i = x)$

$\Rightarrow$ The maximum rectangle area in component $(C)$ is max of over all S(x) for all row $(x)$ existed in $(C)$. Which can be calculate in$ O(Σ(K(x))) = O(|C|)$

$\Rightarrow$ The complexity to calculate all component is $O(Σ(|C|)) = O(n \times m)$